# I need to access model data in a view 2 or 3 or n at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, model

Hello All: I've been struggling with parts of MVC, especially using data from the controller in my View when my view has multiple side by side divs where I need to display model data/entities.

Left Div (Client One)                 Right Div (Client Two)
Left Div (Client Three)               Right Div (Client Four)

I am passing a simple model to my view from the controller.  No matter how I try, it seems that the only way to access the "entities"/rows in the model is via a foreach and iterating over them sequentially.  I really need to get "entities" by their index value, by turning the model data from an IEnumerable into an array and getting entity[ n ].

Is this possible or do I not understand the relationship between the View and the model data.

Here's my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ClientView()
    {

    return View("ClientView", db.Clients.ToList());
```

My model is a simple list of typical client properties with no navigation: FirstName, LastName, Address, etc. In the view, I'm trying to get client 1 in a left side div, and client 2 in a right side div, then a new row and start over.

Thanks much in advance

Allen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your view is strongly typed to List:

```
@Model List<MySoftware.Models.Client>
```

Then you can access the clients by index:

```
Model[0]
Model[1]
Model[2]
```

This is possible because the IList interface allows you to retrieve items by index, just like an array. A List is generally the preferred method as arrays are... well... a bit old fashioned.

However, a better design might be to simply work this into your UI code instead, since this is really a UI display issue. Something like:

```
@Model IEnumerable<MySoftware.Models.Client>

var i = 0;
foreach (var client in Model)
{
    <div> [client details] </div>
    i++;
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        <br/>
}
```

Comment: Brendan: Both methods absolutely work perfectly. Even better, now I understand more about the model data in the view. Many thanks!